# What combination of tags should I use for Linux Mint Debian Edition?

Tags: discussion

As of now, I've simply been using the [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) and [linux-mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) tags together, but since the [linux-mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) description reads:

```
Linux Mint is a Linux distribution closely based on Ubuntu
```

and LMDE doesn't meet this description (it's based on frozen snapshots of Debian Testing, I believe), what course of action should I take?

1. Update the tag wiki (or suggest it be updated since I don't have the reputation)
2. Continue using [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) and [linux-mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) together
3. Create a new [lmde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lmde) tag or something similar
4. etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not extremely familiar with Mint, but:

- if its fairly similar, regardless if  based on Ubuntu or Debian, then propose an edit to the tag wiki. [linux-mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) can include both.
- if they're quite different, then we need two new tags, [mint-ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mint-ubuntu) and [mint-debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mint-debian) (or similar). But I'm guessing they're not really that different.

When asking questions, if the question is something a Debian or Ubuntu expert is likely to be able to answer, add the relevant of [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian) or [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) as well.

A person looking for questions to answer follows (or highlights) the tags they are experts in, and ignores the tags they know nothing of. Tags are used to direct questions to the appropriate expert.

Comment: Please don't add Ubuntu, that puts it in the Ubuntu chat room, and it is frustrating to see questions tagged with ubuntu that have nothing to do with Ubuntu there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, LMDE *is* Debian. It is 100% compatible with Debian repos and is not compatible with Ubuntu's. I also use LMDE and have been simply tagging with Debian, the differences are negligible and essentially consist of some added Mint-tools on a normal Debian testing.

As far as I know, there is nothing on LMDE that you will not also find on Debian apart from some configuration tools which are also installable on other distros anyway. Nevertheless, I have just created an [lmde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lmde) tag which can now be used.